# Is there a way to add a youtube playlist instead of youtube video in header of twenty seventeen template?

Tags: wordpress, youtube, header

The option of adding a youtube video is possible as the background video of the header in the twenty seventeen template on wordpress. I know that simply by pasting the URL of the playlist it will not load but I was wondering if anyone has found a way to load a playlist or random videos through the header?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the files
wp-includes\js\wp-custom-header.js
wp-includes\js\wp-custom-header.min.js

and add the listtype and list to the playerVars.

```
            playerVars: {
                autoplay: 1,
                controls: 0,
                disablekb: 1,
                fs: 0,
                iv_load_policy: 3,
                loop: 1,
                modestbranding: 1,
                playsinline: 1,
                rel: 0,
                listType: 'playlist',
                list: 'youlistID',
                showinfo: 0
            }
```